# Django: How do I refer to app templates that are in a separate templates/app folder succinctly?

Tags: django

In the Django documentation, one is instructed to create templates folders within each app AND then another folder within the templates folder with the name of the app.

So if my appname is 'orders', then the template path for 'index.html' would be:
   `/some_project/orders/templates/orders/index.html`

If I am trying to refer to that template in views, how can I refer to it as just `index.html` rather than `orders/index.html`? The one solution that works is putting all the templates into the `orders/templates/` folder, but that goes against django recommendations.

Comment: Templates are loaded based on your templates path, which looks to be `/some_project/orders/templates/` so if you want to refer only to `index.html` you'd have to put it in `/some_project/orders/templates/index.html`. What's the problem with `orders/index.html`? It allows each app to specify templates without clashing.

Comment: The problem is that if I change the app name, I need to change the paths in various places.

Comment: You can save all the templates in project directory itself, if you want to use `somename.html` instead `appname/somename.html`, with adding a path in DIRS `'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],`in your settings.py. But I recommend you to use base template in project and others in app and use `appname/template.html`

Comment: @racket99 but to change an app name is not something you'd be doing often. An app should be named according to what it does, and therefore to change it's name would be to change it's functionality. Static paths and template paths should be `static/<app>/js/` and `templates/<app>/index.html` so that a project can be consistent & easily organised.